# Value of CDF at negative infinity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have to show that,

$$\lim_{t\to - \infty} \ F_x(t) = 0$$

I proved that
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \ F_x(t) = 1$$

as follows

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} F_x(t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_x(w)\ dw = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_x(w)\ dw = 1$$

But I don't see how to prove the first. Any help? Thanks.

EDIT: I want to prove this for continuous random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space. If $F_X$ is the distribution function for a random variable $X$ defined on this space, then by definition for any $t\in\mathbb R$,
$$
F_X(t) = \mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\leqslant t\}).
$$
Let $E_n = \{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\leqslant -n\}$ for positive integers $n$. Since $E_1\supset E_2\supset\cdots$ and $\mathbb P(\Omega)=1<\infty$, by the "continuity from above" property of measures, we have that
$$
\lim_{t\to-\infty} F_X(t) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(E_n) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right).$$
$$
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\{x \in(-\infty, t)\}$ decreases to empty set as $t$ decreases to $-\infty$ so $F_x(t) \to 0$. By a similar argument $F_x(t) \to 1$ as $ x \to \infty$. Your proof of $F_x(t) \to 1$ as $ x \to \infty$ is not correct since not all CDF's have densities. You cannot use integrals to prove this result.

Comment: I want to prove this for continuous random variables.